# How do we find the volume of an Euclidean ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry, analysis, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, convex-geometry

Following up on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962057/understanding-r-theta-in-mathbbrn-how-does-theta-represent-n-1), I am not sure how the volume of a Euclidean ball has been found in the following extract:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. What does it mean when we say "**the mass of a measure**"?
2. What does rotational invariance mean here, and how was it established?
3. Why do we integrate the function $$x \mapsto \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_1^n x_i^2\right)$$ to find $v_n$?
4. How is the function invariant under rotations?
5. How did we pull out $nv_n$ from the integral in (1.1)?

I apologize for asking too many questions but I'd really appreciate any help I can get in understanding the discourse above! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order 12435 would have been more helpful, but:

1. A mass-$1$ measure on the surface is basically a probability density, so the mass of a region therein is the probability of a random point lying therein ("random" in the sense of whatever distribution we choose to sample). A mass-$M$ measure would be $M$ times that.
2. Rotation about the centre, which is here taken as the origin, doesn't change the surface.
3. The motive is that $\prod_i\exp(-\tfrac12x_i^2)dx_i=\exp(-\tfrac12\underbrace{\sum_ix_i^2}_{r^2})d^nx=r^{n-1}\exp(-\tfrac12r^2)drd\Omega$, with $d\Omega$ the infinitesimal element of solid angle.
4. Rotations also don't change [sums of the form $\sum_ix_iy_i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) because$$R^TR=I\implies(Rx)^TRy=x^TR^TRy=x^Ty.$$
5. Integrating over the surface,$$\left(\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(-\tfrac12x^2)dx\right)^n=nv_n\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}\exp(-\tfrac12r^2)dr$$(because, while $v_n$ is the volume, $nv_n$ is the surface $\int_{S^{n-1}}d\Omega$).

Comment: Why is $d^n x = r^{n-1} dr d\Omega$? Also what's $d\sigma (\theta)$ in the image?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Since volume scales as $r^n$, $d^nx\propto r^{n-1}dr$. I probably should have stuck with their notation; $d\sigma(\theta)=d\Omega$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I feel your answer to $(5)$ may not be right. Why are you using the specific function $\exp \left(- \frac{1}{2}x^2\right)$ to pull out $nv_n$? We should be able to do this in generality, right?

Comment: Also I don't understand where $d\sigma(\theta)$ comes from. Could you add some more details there? I lost clarity when moving from $``d\theta"$ to $d\sigma (\theta)$, and pulling $nv_n$ out. Thanks!

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine The choice of function derives from wanting a product of functions of the $x_i$ to be a function of $r$ alone. The notation $d\sigma(\theta)$ means "a generalization of the $d\theta$ we get on $S_1$", e.g. $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ on $S_2$.